# Alternative way of writing batch job flows

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have just started developing with Spring batch and I have stumbled on something that is tickling my eye.

### Example scenario

Say for example you have 4 steps that you want to run (`step1`, `step2`, `step3` and `step4`) and they should be run in the following way:

1. `step1` is started

   - if `step1` finnishes with exitstatus `COMPLETED` => `step2` is started
   - if `step1` finnishes with exitstatus `FAILED` => `step3` is started
   - if `step1` finnishes with exitstatus `UNKNOWN` => the job will end
2. if `step2` is run

   - if `step2` finnishes with exitstatus `COMPLETED` => `step4` is started
   - if `step2` finnishes with exitstatus `FAILED` => the job will end
3. The job ends

#### Code example 1 (according to documentation: [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#conditionalFlow))

So according to documentation and examples I've seen the scenario chould be written in this way:

```java
@Bean(name = SOME_BEAN)
public Job job() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get(SOME_BEAN)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(step1()).on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode()).to(step2())
            .from(step1()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(step3())
            .from(step1()).on(ExitStatus.UNKNOWN.getExitCode()).end()
            .from(step2()).on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode()).to(step4())
            .from(step2()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).end()
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

The above code tickles my eye as step1 and step2 are mentioned many times.

#### Code example 2 (my own way)

Now I wonder if it is possible to write the same thing but in this way:

```java
@Bean(name = SOME_BEAN)
public Job job() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get(SOME_BEAN)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(step1())
                .on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode()).to(step2())
                .on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(step3())
                .on(ExitStatus.UNKNOWN.getExitCode()).end())
            .from(step2())
                .on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode()).to(step4())
                .on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).end()
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

This way the readability of the code increases a lot (in my opinion).

What I've tested, it seems to work, but I'm buffled that I can't find any examples like this one.

### So my question is:

1. Is it possible to write batch job flows in the way I did?
2. If not, why?
3. If yes, is there a reason why you shouldn't do it like that?

#### Note

As I said, I'm new to this, so if there is something weird/false in my code, please point it out and explain why.

Comment: I gess that original example is much more verbose

Comment: Did both approaches worked for you?

Comment: Yes, both ways worked for me, but I'm wondering why I haven't found examples similar to my example. Is there something wrong with it?